# How to create a shared folder between Homestead and my local machine

Tags: php, laravel, homestead

I'm a computer science graduate. I have just started an internship at a company where they use Laravel. My first task was to install Homestead. I did that.
My second task is to create a shared folder between Homestead and my local machine (I have a macbook pro). I had a quick look on Laravel documentation but I didn't find any article related directly to this subject.
Can somebody help me on this subject? (How can I create a shared folder between Homestead and my local machine?)

Answer (score 7):

Don't worry you are not alone. This is one area that is confusing before one gets used in configuring shared folders on homestead.

```
folders:
    - map: ~/LaravelProjects
    - to: /home/vagrant/LaravelProjects

sites: map: todo
       to: /home/vagrant/LaravelProjects/todo/public
```

`folders: map` contains the root of your projects (the main folder containing your projects) on your local machine. Therefore using `~/LaravelProjects`, it means all your projects are contained within the *LaravelProjects* folder in the home folder. You can make your root folder reside in any place and not necessarily the home folder.

`folders: to` refers to where the root folder `LaravelProjects` will be on the virtual machine. This will mirror the contents of your machines root folder.

`sites:map` will be the host name you will use to access your site. You can name it in any way you like.

`sites:to` is a reference of your document root or public folder that will be served by your web server. Therefore using `/home/vagrant/LaravelProjects/todo/public`, we are telling the web server to serve our app  contained in the project `todo`. If the project files are contained in an inner folder like `src` then we would change it to `/home/vagrant/LaravelProjects/todo/src/public`.

In the chat I saw you asked how to edit the hosts file. You can use, use `sudo open /etc/hosts`

**Update**

Navigating to your shared folder

- Change directory to your Homestead directory
- Run the `vagrant up` command or if the VM is already running, run `vagrant reload --provision`
- After the VM boots, connect to your VM using SSH `vagrant ssh`
- Your prompt should change to `vagrant@homestead:~$` which means you are now logged to the VM.
- Run `pwd` and it should  reflect `/home/vagrant`. This explains why in the Homestead.yaml file `to` was prefixed with `/home/vagrant`
- Run `ls` and `LaravelProjects` should be visible. Contained within `LaravelProjects` should be your `todo` project.
- Navigate to `http://todo` on your local machine and the browser should display the Laravel welcome screen signifying that everything is working as it should

You can now modify your project files on your local machine and the changes will be reflected on the VM and vice versa.

Comment: Thanks for taking time to answer my question. Ok. My Homestead.yaml is now identical to what you wrote in your comment. Next, i need to double check my hosts file. I have added one line to my hosts file: 192.168.10.10  todo (this is the ip from my yaml file). If everything is fine, what should i do next to navigate to my shared folder on my VM? Can you provide a step by step instructions? Starting from opening the Terminal

Comment: When I tried to apply your instructions, it occurred to me that my Laravel installation is not successful!When I ran Vagrant up on my terminal, I got long text displayed on my screen which indicates there is a problem. I extracted some of this text: "/opt/vagrant/embedded/lib/ruby/2.2.0/psych.rb:370:in `parse': (<unknown>): found character that cannot start any token while scanning for the next token at line 17 column 7 (Psych::SyntaxError).."I believe my problem is with configuring Laravel. I was able to install it but i didn't know how to configure it. The official documentation is not clear

Comment: I have reached this point in the laravel's documentation: "After installing Laravel, you should configure your web server's document / web root to be the public directory. The index.php in this directory serves as the front controller for all HTTP requests entering your application." How can i do that?

Answer (score 3):

In your `Homestead.yaml`

```
folders:
    - map: ~/Code
      to: /home/vagrant/Code
```

> According to the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/homestead#configuring-homestead)

Comment: I read this in the documentation but what is "Code"? I have created a folder on my desktop. I named it: LaravelProjects. Inside of this folder, I created a sub folder. I named the sub folder: todo. I want to share my sub folder: todo between Homestead and my local machine. So I went to my Homestead.yaml and I replaced "Code" by the name of my sub folder: todo. Is that correct? And what should i do next?

Comment: `map` is the path to the local folder and `to` is the path the folder on the VM. Put the path your `desktop/LaravelProjects` in `map` and `/home/vagrant/whatever` in `to`

Comment: @vuldo.What should i do after i change my Homestead.yaml file? My questions are basic but this is my first experience with Homestead!

Comment: Run `vagrant halt` and `vagrant up` again then you will be able to get in the VM through `vagrant ssh`

Comment: If this solve your problem don't forget to mark the question as answered, it will be helpful for people who may ask the same.

Comment: ok. I did vagrant halt and then vagrant up. My virtual machine booted successfully. I'm running Vagrant through my terminal. While my virtual machine was booting, I saw my SSH address is: 127.0.0.1:2222. I assumed this is my SSH. So next I wrote: vagrant 127.0.0.1:2222. I got next a bunch of vagrant command! Is this what is supposed to happen? And how can i reach my shared folder from there?

Comment: To connect through ssh you just need to be in the vagrant folder and use `vagrant ssh` then you will in your VM and you can navigate using `cd` though directories. If you edit a file in your shared directory you will be able to see it on the VM

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/130136/discussion-between-hussein-barada-and-vuldo).