# Configuring Homestead (laravel homestead set-up)

Tags: php, laravel, vagrant, homestead

i'm trying to install homestead for my laravel, but i failed during
vagrant up command (next step after configuring homestead), error is like missing file (no such file or directory)

i follow this guide https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/homestead to set up the homestead, and i think i messed up here at configuring shared folders

how do i know what to change here (pathway) correctly in Homestead.yaml file

```
folders:  
    - map: ~/Code                     // this one
      to: /home/vagrant/Code
sites:
    - map: homestead.app
      to: /home/vagrant/Code/Laravel/public       // and this one
```

my directory for this project is like this
= driveC / xampp / htdocs / myproject

Comment: See whether the [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41041625/how-to-create-a-shared-folder-between-homestead-and-my-local-machine/41062565#41062565) may be of help to you.

Answer (score 0):

Change:

`map: ~/Code` to the full path to `myproject`

And this:

`to: /home/vagrant/Code/Laravel/public` to the path of one of your laravel project inside the VM